# Create a New Company in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, admin-panel

I'm new on Magento. today I install Magento. in my tasks I have to create a new company. I don't have company tab/section in my admin panel! I search in google and in all results there is an option under Customers tab called manage company. some questions...

1. whats the meaning of company in magento ? is it a module ?
2. how can I create a company or enable company tab/section in admin panel ?

Comment: Is the company you are trying to create the company that owns the store, or a customer's company, or .... ? If you could describe what you mean by company a bit more it would be easier to help. Welcome to MagentoSE and the world of Magento!

Comment: @AreDubya no. I don't thinks task is realted to customer compnay. I thinks we should have a whole company. in fact creating a store (with magento) for COMPANY_NAME.

Answer (score 3):

On the top menu, go to System -> Configuration, then click the General link under the General tab on the left. You can input the company's information under 'Store Information'. This should take care of it, if I understand your issue.

If you have or are planning to have multiple stores pay attention to the Configuration Scope on the top left. Multiple stores can be created and managed from System -> Manage Stores. Creating multiple stores is out of the scope of this question, but there are many resources out there to help.

Comment: thanks for your good information. I set a name for my store. but now I think client wants another thing and I don't understand correctly. He want to create a new company. I think its different from what I do now.  what do you think ?

Comment: Well, a separate company in the way you have described would be a second store, right? There is information on setting up a second store here : https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-configure-multiple-magento-storefronts.html

Comment: I think I have answered your original question, so if you can accept my answer then ask a new question regarding setting up a second store (if you have a question) I think you will get the best assistance.